# Why is the output of my dictionary in a random, shuffled order as opposed to the order that I want (Python 3.8.3)?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to have my dictionary output information about a music album (the artist's name, the album's name, and the number of songs in the album) in that order. As you can see in my code, the number of songs in the album is not always passed to the function, and that is on purpose.

The problem is, my program is outputting the values of the dictionary in a random, shuffled order, as opposed to the order that I wrote above.

```
def make_album(artist, album_name, songs = None):
    ''' Makes a dictionary describing a music album'''
    if songs:
        album = {artist, album_name, songs}
    else:
        album = {artist, album_name}
    return album
album1 = make_album("Guns n' Roses", "The Spaghetti Incident")
print(album1)
album2 = make_album("Pink Floyd", "The Wall", "10")
print(f"\n{album2}")
album3 = make_album("Smash Brothers", "All Stars")
print(f"\n{album3}")
```

This is an example of an output that I'm getting upon executing the program:

```
{'The Spaghetti Incident', "Guns n' Roses"}

{'10', 'The Wall', 'Pink Floyd'}

{'Smash Brothers', 'All Stars'}
```

Thank you!!!

Btw, this is my time ever asking a programming question on the internet! Brand new coder!!

Btw, I'm running Python 3.8.3.

Comment: 1. Please read [ask]. 2. put your code in the question body, don't link to it. 3. You are using a set, not a dictionary. Sets aren't ordered, not "even" in Python 3.8

Comment: You aren't using dictionaries...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)s. Sets are inherently unordered in Python, and printing them can result in any order.

You want to be using ordered [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)s instead. So instead of

```
album = {artist, album_name, songs}
```

you'd write:

```
album = (artist, album_name, songs)
```

Even better in this case is to use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or a class instead.